# How to create a Dynamic Formula in a Google Spreadsheet based on a dropdown?

Tags: dynamic, drop-down-menu, google-sheets, formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet of containing an Employee Schedule separated daily (each date has its own page).  I need to create a SINGLE summary page with a drop down that will change a formula and display the results.   I currently have the formulas setup so that each employee has their OWN page depending on the employee number that shows a quick summary of when they work for the entire month.   I would like to compress that into a single sheet with a way to dynamically choose from a drop down what name to see.

Here's a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amfumj1fHXzYdElQSGtqZkZ2aHAtdW4wM1d2WTZnMXc&usp=sharing

And here's a direct link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amfumj1fHXzYdElQSGtqZkZ2aHAtdW4wM1d2WTZnMXc&usp=drive_web#gid=34

I'm Looking to change Cell A1 into a drop down that when selected will change the 744 Formulas to look for the selected name.

Current formula: =IF((COUNTIF('1'!B3:P3,"**Katie**"))=0,"","XX")

What i would like to accomplish:  =IF((COUNTIF('1'!B3:P3,"**DROP DOWN SELECTION FROM A1**"))=0,"","XX")

Dropdown will always be a text name (Bob, Sally, Dave R, Adam, Kat, etc)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

IF((COUNTIF('1'!B3:P3,'1'!$a$1))=0,"","XX")

In this way you only need to change the value cell A1 of the sheet called 1.

As for a dropbox, DATA > VALIDATION
- Range '1'!A1
- Criteria, select LIST WITH ITEMS